# Why does my normal map get all messed up when transferring it from blender to unreal engine?

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map, unreal-engine

I am pretty sure that the issue is that the normal map doesn't have non color data on but I am not 100% sure about it and I don't know where to go to do that in unreal engine

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's mapped incorrectly, did you set the right uv map?

Comment: I do not know what exactly your issue is. Apart from some dark smudges on the skin which I can see partially in the original as well, only less intense, it all seems correct. Maybe some face normals are flipped? The skin in general seems to be more saturated, contrasted and glossy in UE, but that's a matter of setting up the material I guess. I do not think you need to set the normal map to non-color in UE as far as I know... but if so, that's a question for a UE forum, not Blender. Or do you mean everything on the left being so dark? That's the shadow of the hat, isn't it? ;)